# Trial form is not working

Tags: administration, isv

We are an ISV partner and suddenly our trial form stopped working and it reports on [image]

Apparently the form action http://www.salesforce.com/leadcapture/PartnerSignupServlet is no longer relevant, did you happen to experience this?

Update: Apparently it does create a trial org, although the "opps" message is still there when creating a new trial.

Comment: I am also an ISV partner, it just happened to me, are you sure it is working? I do not get any emails after successful trial registration.